# Experience Optimization cartridge in Sites 9 XO?

Tags: web8.5, experience-optimization, sites-9

Looking at the 8.5 documentation for XO, there is a cartridge which is responsible for putting all the defined triggers from the `trigger-types.xml` to a claim in ADF, the [Experience Optimization cartridge](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dexperience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1564039988234&currentQuery=experience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7B1FE512-E9FF-49A0-9E15-568FD6D41085&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-7B1FE512-E9FF-49A0-9E15-568FD6D41085.xml&docid=GUID-7B1FE512-E9FF-49A0-9E15-568FD6D41085&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false).

> The Claim Processors used in the Experience Optimization cartridge are packaged in the `smarttarget_cartridge.jar`

Before an XO query is executed, the entire content of the Claim Store is cross referenced against the claim containing the triggers, and and only the  matching ones are sent to FH.

This makes perfect sense, yet I cannot find anything similar in Sites 9's XO (using ElasticSearch). Is this filtering now built into the system or where is it?

Below is a screenshot of the documentation comparing the "XO cartridge reference" sections of [8.5](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dexperience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1564039988234&currentQuery=experience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4FAA9496-42A6-4C12-BD69-6490662A4A5C&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-13607469-7556-4399-97BC-40D0CB342386.xml&docid=GUID-4FAA9496-42A6-4C12-BD69-6490662A4A5C&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) and [9](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-52619D29-DB30-4E94-9257-C6C7239A4B77#docid=GUID-4FAA9496-42A6-4C12-BD69-6490662A4A5C&filename=GUID-13607469-7556-4399-97BC-40D0CB342386.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4FAA9496-42A6-4C12-BD69-6490662A4A5C&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+Sites-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dexperience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1564040030083&currentQuery=experience%2520optimization%2520cartridge&currentScope=), and there is no mention of anything similar for 9. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cartridge is indeed no longer needed as the problem it was solving (URL size) doesn't exist in the new version with Elasticsearch.